# What are all relevant characteristic and properties to delta

Tags: chaos-theory

[image: definition of sensitive dependence on initial conditions]

What are all relevant characteristic and properties to delta? I mean if our system was more dependent on initial condition (I don't know if this expression is true), for greater amount of delta, Is there any particular properties would observed?

Comment: I don't think there is much to say, when it comes to comparing functions on *how sensitive* they are to initial conditions. This is because we don't know which $y$ is such that $|f^n (x) - f^n (y) | > \delta$, only that such a $y$ exists in a neighourhood of $x$.

Comment: So the best I can think is, if $f$ has a higher "delta" than $g$, then there are $y_1$ and $y_2$ such that $|x-y_1 |<\epsilon$, $|x - y_2 |<\epsilon$, and $|f^n (x) - f^n (y_1)| > |g^m (x) - g^m (y_2)|$ for natural numbers $n,m$